# mvc4-condition data annotation validation on model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a nested PersonalAddress view model.For both CommAddress & PermanentAddress  all properties are mandatory.

I am using addressDetails model for both communication address & permanent address in mvc4 view.But for permanent address all properties are not mandatory.How can I make these required properties optional in case of permanent address.

```
 public class AddressDetails
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Error Message...")]
    public string Road { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
    public string Sector { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalAddress
{

    public AddressDetails CommAddress { get; set; }

    public AddressDetails PermanentAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create separate view models, or include a property (say) `bool IsMandatory` and use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) or similar `[RequiredIfTrue("IsMandatory")]` attribute

Comment: you can point to a specific metadata class, but im not sure if this will make things cleaner or not. check out : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to you?

```
public class AddressDetails
{
    public string Road { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ReqAddressDetailsMetadata))]
public class ReqAddressDetail : AddressDetails
{
    public class ReqAddressDetailsMetadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
        public string Road { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
        public string Sector { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message...")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}

public class PersonalAddress
{

    public ReqAddressDetail CommAddress { get; set; }

    public AddressDetails PermanentAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to use extra properties for same thing.Is there any way to pass some metadata value from CommAddress property to its child properties. or is there any way to differentiate between commAddress city field and permanentAddress city in custom validation provide .

Comment: You can also create your own attribute.